# Storing search result for paging and sorting

Tags: c#, asp.net, search, search-engine

I've been implementing MS Search Server 2010 and so far its really good. Im doing the search queries via their web service, but due to the inconsistent [results](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/searchserverdevelopersandcustomization/thread/55ac036c-40c0-4f06-b3f4-c867aee09193), im thinking about caching the result instead.

The site is a small intranet (500 employees), so it shouldnt be any problems, but im curious what approach you would take if it was a bigger site.

I've googled abit, but havent really come over anything specific. So, a few questions:

- What other approaches are there? And why are they better?
- How much does it cost to store a dataview of 400-500 rows? What sizes are feasible?
- Other points you should take into consideration.

Any input is welcome :)

Comment: Have you looked at Apache SOLR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to employ many techniques to pull this off successfully.

**First**, you need some sort of persistence layer.  If you are using a plain old website, then the user's session would be the most logical layer to use.  If you are using web services (meaning session-less) and just making calls through a client, well then you still need some sort of application layer (sort of a shared session) for your services.  Why?  This layer will be home to your database result cache.

**Second**, you need a way of caching your results in whatever container you are using (session or the application layer of web services).  You can do this a couple of ways... If the query is something that any user can do, then a simple hash of the query will work, and you can share this stored result among other users.  You probably still want some sort of GUID for the result, so that you can pass this around in your client application, but having a hash lookup from the queries to the results will be useful.  If these queries are unique then you can just use the unique GUID for the query result and pass this along to the client application.  This is so you can perform your caching functionality...

The caching mechanism can incorporate some sort of fixed length buffer or queue... so that old results will automatically get cleaned out/removed as new ones are added.  Then, if a query comes in that is a cache miss, it will get executed normally and added to the cache.

**Third**, you are going to want some way to page your result object...  the Iterator pattern works well here, though probably something simpler might work... like fetch **X** amount of results starting at point **Y**.  However the Iterator pattern would be better as you could then remove your caching mechanism later and page directly from the database if you so desired.

**Fourth**, you need some sort of pre-fetch mechanism (as others suggested).  You should launch a thread that will do the full search, and in your main thread just do a quick search with the top **X** number of items.  Hopefully by the time the user tries paging, the second thread will be finished and your full result will now be in the cache.  If the result isn't ready, you can just incorporate some simple loading screen logic.

This should get you some of the way... let me know if you want clarification/more details about any particular part.

I'll leave you with some more tips...

1. You don't want to be sending the entire result to the client app (if you are using Ajax or something like an IPhone app).  Why?  Well because that is a huge waste.  The user likely isn't going to page through all of the results... now you just sent over 2MB of result fields for nothing.
2. Javascript is an awesome language but remember it is still a client side scripting language...  you don't want to be slowing the user experience down too much by sending massive amounts of data for your Ajax client to handle.  Just send the prefetched result your client and additional page results as the user pages.
3. Abstraction abstraction abstraction... you want to abstract away the cache, the querying, the paging, the prefetching... as much of it as you can.  Why?  Well lets say you want to switch databases or you want to page directly from the database instead of using a result object in cache... well if you do it right this is much easier to change later on.  Also, if using web services, many many other applications can make use of this logic later on.

Now, I probably suggested an over-engineered solution for what you need :).  But, if you can pull this off using all the right techniques, you will learn a ton and have a very good base in case you want to extend functionality or reuse this code.

Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: I forgot to answer. Sorry. I did use caching for web service calls and session for web server searches. Thanks for the extensive answer, really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the slow part of the search is the full-text searching, not the result retrieval.  How about caching the resulting resource record IDs?  Also, since it might be true that search queries are often duplicated, store a hash of the search query, the query, and the matching resources.  Then you can retrieve the next page of results by ID.  Works with AJAX too.

Since it's an intranet and you may control the searched resources, you could even pre-compute a new or updated resource's match to popular queries during idle time.

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit that I am not terribly familiar with MS Search Server so this may not apply. I have often had situations where an application had to search through hundreds of millions of records for result sets that needed to be sorted, paginated and sub-searched in a SQL Server though. Generally what I do is take a two step approach. First I grab the first "x" results which need to be displayed and send them to the browser for a quick display. Second, on another thread, I finish the full query and move the results to a temp table where they can be stored and retrieved quicker. Any given query may have thousands or tens of thousands of results but in comparison to the hundreds of millions or even billions of total records, this smaller subset can be manipulated very easily from the temp table. It also puts less stress on the other tables as queries happen. If the user needs a second page of records, or needs to sort them, or just wants a subset of the original query, this is all pulled from the temp table.

Logic then needs to be put into place to check for outdated temp tables and remove them. This is simple enough and I let the SQL Server handle that functionality. Finally logic has to be put into place for when the original query changes (significant perimeter changes) so that a new data set can be pulled and placed into a new temp table for further querying. All of this is relatively simple.

Users are so used to split second return times from places like google and this model gives me enough flexibility to actually achieve that without needing the specialized software and hardware that they use.

Hope this helps a little.

Answer (score 0):

Tim's answer is a great way to handle things if you have the ability to run the initial query in a second thread and the logic (paging / sorting / filtering) to be applied to the results requires action on the server ..... otherwise  ....

If you can use AJAX, a 500 row result set could be called into the page and paged or sorted on the client.  This can lead to some really interesting features .... check out the datagrid solutions from jQueryUI and Dojo for inspiration!

And for really intensive features like arbitrary regex filters and drag-and-drop column re-ordering you can totally free the server.

Loading the data to the browser all at once also lets you call in supporting data (page previews etc) as the user "requests" them ....

The main issue is limiting the data you return per result to what you'll actually use for your sorts and filters.

The possibilities are endless :)

Comment: But hopefully, your search algorithm brings good results early on, so you'd be loading 490 results and page preview images unnecessarily